How Can I Make Statics In Admin Panel like Shopify Using Next.js and Scss
I am New To Next.js and Scss and as my first project I am Trying to Build a E-Commerce Website With an Admin Panel.
I am Confused in some stuff but thanks to PayLoad CMS made it possible for me to finish about 45% of my task.
However, when I was building it, I considered including an admin panel with static content, similar to Shopify.Okay, so I have a panel to work with, but I'm not sure how to add statics to my admin panel.
Here are some screenshots of the Shopify admin panel for your reference.img1 ,img2
I Tried Searching Online But didn't find anything useful, as most of the things just offering a template for the dashboard.
I also Found out that their are some libraries which offers charts for websites but again Couldn't find out how to trigger them in real time
